# Outlook rule to move Sent Items to another person's Sent Items folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2007

It appears that when sending mail, the rule I use to move the sent item to another mailbox' sent items folder isn't processed. If I manually use the "process rules now" button it works as expected.

Is there any way to:

- put these sent items directly into the mailbox when using "send as", without rules
- if rules need to be used, how do I make sure they are processed right after sending the mail

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can automate that, since rules are designed to run before email is delivered, not before **sent mail** is processed.

The only other options are to manually trigger the rule (as you've already stated) or create a macro that does the move, and assign the macro to a button on the toolbar. Although that would be easier to initiate, it would be much harder to design the macro to do what you want.

Comment: could you elaborate on the macro's, please?

Comment: http://www.ureader.com/msg/1081942.aspx

Comment: I see, well that wouldn't help me much as 1) it'd be a PITA to get it to work as you said, and 2) I could just as well make a rule to do it and then press the "process rules" after sending, instead of pressing the macro button, so it wouldn't really improve much (if at all)

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Sent Items* folder's "ItemAdd" event instead of *MailItem*'s "Send" event.

I found [this post](https://www.itprotoday.com/email-and-calendaring/outlook-2010-move-mailitems-after-sending) by Rob Gravelle explaining why it is easier to use the event of an email being added to "Sent Items" as a trigger.

Gravelle provides this sample VBA script that moves the Sent item to "FOSS Export (CR-035)" if the recipient address contains "RobGravelleAndCo.com":

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oSentItems As Items
Private oBusinessFolder As MAPIFolder
Private Const BUSINESS_FOLDER = "FOSS Export (CR-035)"
Private Const PARTNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "RobGravelleAndCo.com"
    
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim oSentItemsFolder As MAPIFolder  
    Set oSentItemsFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set oSentItems = oSentItemsFolder.Items
    Set oBusinessFolder = oSentItemsFolder.Parent.Folders(BUSINESS_FOLDER)
End Sub
    
Private Sub oSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    Dim oRecipient As Recipient
    Select Case item.Class
        Case olMail, olMeetingRequest
        For Each oRecipient In item.Recipients
            If InStr(1, oRecipient.Address, PARTNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS) Then
                item.Move oBusinessFolder
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

I wanted Outlook to choose the Sent Items folder based on the "From" field, instead of the "To" field. I modified Gravelle's script into a VSTO add-in that prompts for a "Sent Items" folder each time you use a new "From" address. I posted the source code on GitHub if anyone wants to try it or fork it:

[SentFolderByFrom](https://github.com/browlry/SentFolderByFrom)