# GSSMO: Emails sent by delegate save to delegate's personal "Sent Items" folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-workspace

An quirk of G Suite's email delegation feature is that

- items sent by a delegate via the Gmail web app are stored in the delegator's "Sent Items" folder, but
- items sent by a delegate via G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook (GSSMO) are stored in the delegate's Sent Items folder, where they can't be seen by the delegator.

This caused [complaints from some users](https://support.google.com/a/forum/AAAA034zvV8IPziQzSvhTI), but Google declined to change the behavior and [documented it](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/170957?hl=en) instead:

> **Can't see delegate's Sent Items:** Messages sent on your behalf are available in the delegate's Sent Items folder but not yours. As a result, you won't see messages sent on your behalf until a reply appears in your inbox.

Are there any non-Google ways to move sent items to the delegator's Sent Items folder?

I thought I could set up a Rule in Outlook on "messages I send", but the "from" condition is only available for "messages I receive".

Exchange users have a [similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1448208/allow-users-to-sign-into-exchange-email-with-their-own-account-one-email-addre/1448554#1448554) that can be addressed with a [registry value](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/shared-mailboxes/sent-mail-is-not-saved), but that fix doesn't apply to GSSMO.

Related:
[Outlook rule to move Sent Items to another person's Sent Items folder](https://superuser.com/questions/179466/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small VSTO add-on that watches for items to be added to the user's main "Sent Items" folder. Once an item is added, it checks the "From" address and moves it to a different folder when appropriate.

I posted the source code to GitHub if anyone wants to try it out:

[SentFolderByFrom](https://github.com/browlry/SentFolderByFrom)